# Processing noise implementation has strictly positive range

Tags: processing, perlin-noise, simplex-noise, noise-generator

At [this](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) page, and in the docs for p5.js, Perlin noise is described as having an output range of [0,1], but all other implementations I've found have a small range symmetric about 0, and it seems that this is what should theoretically hold as well. What's going on with Processing's implementation of Perlin noise? What are they doing differently? How can I replicate this in, say, python?

Answer (score 0):

Processing is open-source. You can view the source code of the `noise()` function [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java) (currently line 5293).

You also might want to read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18261982/873165) which discusses the output range of Perlin noise.